# Replace only last NA given ID from another column

Tags: r

Here is sample: data and wrong solution:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5), val=c(NA,1.5,1,NA,NA,5,NA,2,NA), rep=1:9)
```

Replace last `NA` given `id` from another column. Here is what I tried (among others):

```
funrep <- function(x) { is.na(tail(x, 1)) } 
df$val[as.logical(with(df, ave(val, id, FUN=funrep)))] <- df$rep[as.logical(with(df, ave(val, id, FUN=funrep)))]
```

The above replaces figures given `id` from another column where there is no `NA`.

Desired output:

```
 id val rep val2
  1  NA   1   NA 
  1 1.5   2  1.5
  2 1.0   3  1.0
  2  NA   4  NA
  2  NA   5  5 
  3 5.0   6  5.0
  4  NA   7  7
  5 2.0   8  2.0
  5  NA   9  9
```

**EDIT** : the values in column `val2` has been corrected. Also I prefer base R solution. Thanks.

Comment: `df$val2 <- ifelse(is.na(df$val), rep, val)`

Comment: @Heroka: sorry, I made mistake in the example. Please check gain. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`, create "val2" column from "val", get the row index (`.I`) based on the logical condition grouped by "ID", extract that column (`$V1`).  Using that index in the "i", we assign "val2" to those corresponding elements in "rep".

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, val2:= val][, .I[1:.N==.N & is.na(val)] , id]$V1
df[i1, val2:= as.numeric(rep)]
df
#     id val rep val2
#1:  1  NA   1   NA
#2:  1 1.5   2  1.5
#3:  2 1.0   3  1.0
#4:  2  NA   4   NA
#5:  2  NA   5  5.0
#6:  3 5.0   6  5.0
#7:  4  NA   7  7.0
#8:  5 2.0   8  2.0
#9:  5  NA   9  9.0
```

---

Using `base R`, we create a new column with `transform`, `split` the data.frame to list with `split`, use `ifelse` to change the values in 'val2' with 'rep' that satisfies the condition, and `unsplit` to get the expected output.

```
 unsplit(lapply(split(transform(df, val2=val), df$id), 
     function(x) transform(x, val2=ifelse(is.na(val2) & 
       1:nrow(x)==nrow(x), rep, val2))), df$id)
```

Or using `ave`

```
 i2 <- with(df, ave(is.na(val), id, FUN=function(x) x &
               seq_along(x)==length(x)))
 with(df, ifelse(i2, rep, val))
```

Comment: @Maximilian  Updated with a base R solution

Comment: Thanks for the `ave` solution, the `"unsplit"` solution is really slow. With `data.table` I'm not so confident so in case something goes wrong I cannot fix it, thank you again.